# jquery checkbox alert text (but not value attr )

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

the example is working fine, but is that possible to make it alert $200,000 instead of 'value' ?

```js
var checkboxes = $('input[name="price[]"]');

checkboxes.on("click", function() {
  var $checked = checkboxes.filter(":checked"),
    checkedValues = $checked.map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get();
  alert(checkedValues);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="searchFilter">
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" class="cb_price" value="1"> $200,000 to $299,999</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" class="cb_price" value="3"> $300,000 to $399,999</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" class="cb_price" value="5"> $400,000 to $499,999</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" class="cb_price" value="8"> $500,000+</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line: `return this.value;`  to return the `innerText` of parent element (instead of input's value).

Snippet:

```js
var checkboxes = $('input[name="price[]"]');

checkboxes.on("click", function() {
  var $checked = checkboxes.filter(":checked"),
    checkedValues = $checked.map(function() {
      return this.parentElement.innerText;
    }).get();
  alert(checkedValues);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="searchFilter">
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" class="cb_price" value="1"> $200,000 to $299,999</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" class="cb_price" value="3"> $300,000 to $399,999</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" class="cb_price" value="5"> $400,000 to $499,999</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" class="cb_price" value="8"> $500,000+</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks . but how does it actually detect it ? from the code the $200,000 is not 'inside' the tag of checkbox

Comment: `this.parentElement.innerText` means something like: the text of the parent element (`li`) of the checked checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Using vanilla JS:

```js
const checkboxes = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[name="price[]"]')];

for (const checkbox of checkboxes) {
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    const checkedValues = checkboxes.filter(cb=>cb.checked).map(cb=>cb.parentElement.textContent);
    console.log(checkedValues);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="searchFilter">
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" class="cb_price" value="1"> $200,000 to $299,999</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" class="cb_price" value="3"> $300,000 to $399,999</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" class="cb_price" value="5"> $400,000 to $499,999</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="price[]" class="cb_price" value="8"> $500,000+</li>
</ul>
```